# preg_match_all regex with quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am parsing a php file and I want to get an specific variable value from it.

say $str = '$title = "Hello world" ; $author = "Geek Batman"';

I want to get "Geek Batman" given variable say, $author. But I want to do this dynamically.

Let's say from an html form input value
so

```
$myDynamicVar = $_POST['var']; //coming from form in the HTML
//$myDynamicVar = '$title = '; (the user will provide the dollar sign and the equal sign)

$pattern = '/\'. $myDynamicVar . '"(.*?)"/s';
$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $output, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

the result is coming out empty, although I know the variable exists.
I am assuming it has to do with double quotes and I am not escaping them correctly.

Anyone can help?

Comment: What is the background for this task? Why do you need that in first place?

Comment: @zerkms I want to create a GUI to modify php variables (so a user with no php skills can update a website generated based on php variables)

Comment: Can you load the php file? If so, you could get the contents of your variable as `echo $$myDynamicVar`.

Comment: @Stephani Alves: why don't you modify text based files, like `.ini` then? And then read them in your php code

Comment: @StephaniAlves it should be easier and safer (and more correct) to store those values in a database or a config file (XML maybe?) and retrieve the values via PHP than to parse a php file directly

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós I agree, I would have done this completely different. But, I have to deal with what I currently have. Which is a flat php file with a bunch of variables (like 500 flat files)

Comment: @Stephani Alves: if you follow your current idea - you will turn just a "bad" solution into a "terrible" one. Make sure the next person to support it doesn't know where you live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit crazy to parse php code with regular expressions when a [proper tokenizer](http://php.net/token_get_all) is available:

```
$str = '$title = "Hello world" ; $author="Geek Batman"';

$tokens = token_get_all('<?php ' . $str);

$state = 0;
$result = null;

foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    switch ($state) {
        case 0:
            if ($token[0] == T_VARIABLE && $token[1] == '$author') {
                $state = 1;
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            if ($token[0] == T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) {
                $result = $token[1];
                break 2;
            }
            break;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/bcV9ol

Comment: very neat using the tokenizer :)

Comment: Thank you for the great solution. It worked for what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

The problem more likely has to do with the special characters that the user enters that have some meaning in regex (mainly the dollar in your case, but maybe other characters too). So you need to escape them (with [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg-quote)) so the regex matches a `$` instead of interpreting it as `end of line`.

(the way you were using to escape the dollar didn't work, it was escaping the quote to close the string, instead of escaping the dollar in the variable contents)

Try the following:

```
$myDynamicVar = $_POST['var']; //coming from form in the HTML
//$myDynamicVar = '$title = '; (the user will provide the dollar sign and the equal sign)

$pattern = '/'. preg_quote($myDynamicVar) . '"(.*?)"/s';
$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $output, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```